# Web site analyser

Tags: statistics, analytics

This is sort of a statistics question. I am looking for a website analyser, not quite like google analytics. I want the analyser to crawl the website itself and record all the data on a page. Images, size of image and so on.

Even if it is just a library then its a start for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wget to download all the images on a site.  Doubt it's the best way to do this though.  Chrome's Inspect Element function has information on the sizes of all images on a page, if that's more what you're looking for.